# How to join a table to multiple colums with sql then access data with php?

Tags: php, sql

So I have a table "lyket_elements" (with  id, field1, field2, field3) and a table "lyket_entries" with source.id and series_id (these hold the id of one of the lyket_elements.
here is the sql I have so far.

```
$sql = "SELECT LE.id, ele1.field1, ele2.field1\n"
. "  FROM lyket_entries AS LE\n"
. " INNER JOIN lyket_elements AS ele1 \n"
. "         ON ele1.id = LE.source_id \n"
. " INNER JOIN lyket_elements AS ele2\n"
. "         ON ele2.id = LE.series_id";
```

then I'm trying to access field1, field 2, or field 3 from the lyket_elements table that correlates to the id from lyket_entires source_id or series_id.

```
<?php echo $all_entries['1']->ele1.field1; ?>

<?php echo $all_entries['1']->ele2.field1; ?>
```

However, the above is just giving me a string of "field1" and "field2", not the actual data inside. When I var_dump($all_entries) there is no ele1 or ele2 in there, the data seems to be there but all under "lyket_elements"

I can do

```
<?php echo $all_entries['1']->lyket_elements; ?>
```

and that gives me 1 element, but I can't seem to target the correct element that corresponds to the different id's contained in source_id and series_id.

ANSWER: So the above query works, but I needed to add an additional AS to each element in the SELECT clause to be able to access the correct elements it seems. Here is my final query that worked.

```
$sql = "SELECT LE.id, ele1.element_field1 AS ele1field1, ele2.element_field1 AS ele2field1\n"
. "  FROM lyket_entries AS LE\n"
. " LEFT JOIN lyket_elements AS ele1 \n"
. "         ON ele1.id = LE.source_id \n"
. " LEFT
JOIN lyket_elements AS ele2\n"
. "         ON ele2.id = LE.series_id";
```

then access them as such

```
<?php echo $all_entries['1']->ele1field1; ?>

<?php echo $all_entries['1']->ele2field1; ?>
```

Comment: Have you tried Google???

Comment: yeah, can't seem to find anything relevent. I've found some posts on how to do the join, which is how i got the sql above, but I cant find anything that tells me how to access the data separately as the above sql seems to grab all the elements under the same name of "lyket_elements", which doesnt allow me to access them individually.

Comment: No one can help you if no one can understand you.  Read this.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: not sure how to make it more clear if you don't say which part isn't clear.

Comment: Post all of your page code so we can see what you are trying to do.

Comment: Is there any reason why you are using two inner joins on the same table?

You could use only one join with the two conditions like this:



"INNER JOIN lyket_elements as ele1 ON ele1.id = LE.source_id OR ele1.id = LE.series_id"


Then maybe having only one alias for table lyket_elements will make it easier for you to access the fields.

Comment: Sample input?  Expected output?  Table structure?

Comment: Is that more clear? I'm new to this so it's hard to know exactly what is needed. Sorry, and thank you

Comment: where are is the code that sets your controls to the row values?

Comment: sorry @briskovich I'm not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fields will be prefixed with the aliases you've assigned. For example:

```
LE.id
ele1.field1
ele2.field2
```

Just as you have done in your `ON` statements. You *are* assigning two aliases to the same table, `lyket_elements` which will make things confusing, but doable.

Probably the best thing to do is to specify the columns you need from the query, for example:

```
$sql = "SELECT LE.id AS foo, ele1.field1 AS bar, ele2.field2 AS glorp, ...
```

That will have two benefits, speeding up the query and returning the data with an easy way to identify where it is coming from.

Comment: ty Jay, however when I <?php echo $variable->ele1.field1; ?> it just echo's out the string  "field1". When I do a var_dump, all the information is there, but there is no ele1, or ele2, they are all grabbed from the database but they all have "lyket_elements" as their prefix, so I can't access them individually for some reason.

Comment: You may need to specify the columns in your select. Updating the answer.

Comment: Ty again Jay, however, my query does not seem to be bringing ele1 over. When I do a php vardump of the query, there is no ele1 at all in the variable. I can do $variable->field1 but not $variable->ele1.field1 for some reason. 

I've updated my original post, hopefully, it makes it more clear.

Comment: OH so, I'm not sure if this is what you were saying and I didn't understand, BUT, your answer leads me to the right answer either way. I needed to add an additional AS statement to the select. Adjust ur post to clarify this point and I'll assign you credit since without ur post I wouldn't have gotten there.  Thank you so much.